# click event on DIV not working in IE

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer, html, click

here is my code (html)

```
<div id="navig" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal;">
<div id="navfirst"><a href="#"  style="text-decoration: none;">First</a></div>
<div id="navnum"><a href="#"  style="text-decoration: none;">1</a></div>
<div id="navnum"><a href="#"  style="text-decoration: none;">2</a></div>
<div id="navnum"><a href="#"  style="text-decoration: none;">3</a></div>
<div id="navnum"><a href="#"  style="text-decoration: none;">4</a></div>
<div id="navnum"><a href="#"  style="text-decoration: none;">5</a></div>
<div id="navlast"><a href="#"  style="text-decoration: none;">Last</a></div>
```

```
 $( document ).ready(function( ) {
 $('div #navnum').click( function ( ) {
    var divtext =  $(this).text( ) ;
    $( this ).css('background-color', '#f99');
    $( this ).prevAll( ).css('background-color', '');
    $( this ).nextAll( ).css('background-color', '');
    $('#pgnum').html( '<p>clicked page number ' + divtext  + '</p>' ).fadeIn( 100 );
});

 });
```

works fine on firefox and chrome, but not in IE 8, how to make it work in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be declaring the same `id` on multiple elements in a HTML page. `id` is supposed to be unique to the `document`. Instead, try switching your divs that are using `navnum` for an `id` to use them as a `class`. `class` names can be shared throughout your page. For example:

```
<div class="navnum"><a href="#"  style="text-decoration: none;">1</a></div>
```

Then for your click handler:

```
$('div.navnum').click( function ( )
```

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uPMXq/1/) you can test in IE.